# How to keep extent map only show limited number of layers in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, map-series

I have a map series of counties in my state that also has an extent indicator map frame, which is a state county map highlighting the currently selected county.
I'd like to include some layers for the main map, but not include it in the extent indicator. If I remove or turn off any layer in either frame, it's automatically removed or turned off in the other frame as well. Is there a way to display just selected layers in the extent frame?

Comment: Are you using only one map in the layout? If better to use two maps, one as the main map and the other one just for extent indicator. You can set map series filtering in both of them

Comment: Yes, just one map in the layout. Getting it to work using scale level visibility. Don't know how to keep both maps synced.

Comment: You can sync them from layout options. Both can be used in map series also